# string.Contains as a predicate not a function call?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I found this sample of code on SO (can't remember from where :/) that allowed me to check for line code arguments when launching my application :

```
if (e.Args.Length == 0 || e.Args.Any("-show".Contains))
{
  //show interface...
}
```

I just can't seem to understand how the `"-show".Contains` works.
And if there's any difference with a (classic) `x => x.Contains('"-show")` (except for the evident typing gain).

Works like a charm but I'd like to understand why, I feel like something big is hapening.

Comment: Link expression Any(...) takes the argument `Func<TSource, bool> predicate` and Method `Contains(...)` satisfies exact that function signature. Taking a string as parameter and returning a bool. So no need to wrap the Contains in a anonymous function.

Comment: Side note: this is a *terrible* way of checking argument value.

Comment: Yes, as i read the answers I realized that it's not a good solution (and changed it back to a lambda expression(x=>x=="-show").

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This:

```
.Any("-show".Contains)
```

is basically shorthand for this:

```
.Any(s => "-show".Contains(s))
```

The `Any` method takes a delegate as a parameter and you can create that delegate in a number of ways.  The first snippet uses a method group while the second uses a Lambda.

It's not really accurate to say that the first is shorthand for the second because method groups predate Lambdas, but if you think in terms of Lambdas when calling LINQ methods like `Any` then it is effectively the case.

Comment: Note that method group only work when the delegate receives maximum one parameter. When there is more parameters the method group can't be used.

Comment: It's not a shorthand, it's just exactly what the delegate accepts

Comment: So basically, that's a delegate construction from a method group (hence no parentheses) here? I'm  not really aware with delegates or method groups.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's basically the same as using `AddressOf` in VB.

Comment: @Phoque Conceptually, it's just using the bound method (A bound method is just an instance method attached to a particular instance, so a definition for `this` inside it.) as an object and passing it as an argument. Lambdas are just inline definitions of methods. Though I won't vouch for that reflecting the underlying implementation.

Comment: Personally, I would use the full lambda syntax.  I find the method group format to be clever, but more difficult to read.  This is especially true if any newer developers will have to read the code.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'd disagree: the lambda vairable simply adds noise to a simple check, and anyone who is confused by this can simply hover their cursor over the `Contains` and IntelliSense will tell you exactly what is being called. As for "this may confuse newer developers" - I chucked that advice out the window years ago. If it confuses them, and they're any good, they'll either figure it out themselves, research it themselves, or ask. If they don't do any of those things, you probably don't want them touching your code.

Comment: @IanKemp The point is code isn't *meant* to take long to figure out. That's time better put into the rest of development. They *ought* to be able to, if they're worth their salt, but they shouldn't spend longer than strictly necessary. Hard-to-understand code is missing the point of having a human-readable language to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

As @jmcilhiney already said, it shorthand for:

```
.Any(s => "-show".Contains(s))
```

`Contains` is a function accepting 1 parameter which is of type string (and returns a boolean). `Any()` in this  case wants a function that needs 1 param which is a string and that returns a boolean. So rather than adding an extra lambda warapper `s=>`, you can directly return `.Contains`

In technical terms this is a:

```
Func<string, boolean> //1 param string, output: boolean
```

Note that this code matches any argument that is a part of `-show`

thus either of the following arguments do match!

```
-show
-s
sh
ow
h
w
// etc..
```

Comment: *any argument that **is** a part of `-show`* - `foos` contains both `o` and `s` but it will not match

Answer (score 4):

[`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a `Func<TSource, bool>` delegate. So any function that returns a `bool` and takes an argument that is of the same type as the elements of the collection (`string` in your case) can be applied. This can be an existing function, or a lambda expression.

The signature of `String.Contains` is

```
bool Contains(string s)
```

That's why you can pass it to `Any()`

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be `x => "-show".Contains(x)` rather than what you've shown.

After that you'll realise that all you're doing by introducing the `x` based lambda is to create a function accepting a single `string` argument and returning a `bool` and *wrapping* a function that accepts a single `string` and returns a `bool`. There's no need for the wrapper.